# global condition on vector

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements, global

.Hi

I would like to make a comparison operation on my vector: I got one with numerical values that I want to transform in 2^. However if one value is greater than 65000 after it has be transformed I would like there's no transformation for the entire vector.

Currently I'm trying this:

```
final<-ifelse((2^vec>65000)vec,2^vec)
```

It works great but for each value. So if one is greater than 65000 after transformation it this code returns me the initial value but if does'nt exceed 65000 it returns me the transformed value and I have a mixed vector with transformed and non transformed values.

here an example:

```
> vec
32.82    576.47     36.45     78.93      8.77     63.28    176.86      1.88    291.97     35.59
```

And the result after my code

```
> final
```

32.820000 576.470000  36.450000  78.930000 436.549065  63.280000 176.860000  3.680751 291.970000  35.590000

here, you can see that some values have been transformed en some not. In this kind of situation finally I would like fina=vec. I tried with a "break" instead of vec for the "yes" condition in the ifelse but it does'nt work. Probably something like that could work but I don't what.

If someone has an idea  ^^
 Thanks

Comment: Lets see if this is clearer: if *any* values in `vec` are over 65000 you want to get `log2(vec)` (for all values in `vec`), otherwise you just want `vec`?

Comment: In fact it's if one value in 2^vec is over 65000 I want vec (I made a mistake and edit message)

Comment: When you say "if one value" do you mean "only one value"? Not two values, or three values, but *one and only one* value? My code will need to change if you really only want to transform if *exactly* one value is over the threshold.

Comment: yes :if only one value among all values of my vector is greater than the threshold I don't want to make the transformation

Comment: So you only want to do the transformation if *two or more* values are over the threshold?

Comment: no ^^ I want to do the transformation if and only if ALL my values are under the threshold when they are transformed. Or, value after value I transformed them with 2^ and if a value (after this transformation) is over 65000 I want to go back and keep the initial vector (without transformation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
log_if_bigger = function(vec, thresh){
  if(any(vec>thresh)){
    return(log2(vec))
  }else{
    return(vec)
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
# if any values, bigger than 0 then log - here there are:
> log_if_bigger(c(1,2,3,4),0)
[1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.584963 2.000000


# if any values bigger than 9 then log - here there arent:
> log_if_bigger(c(1,2,3,4),9)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Then you just want something like:

```
final = log_if_bigger(vec, 65000)
```

or possibly:

```
final = log_if_bigger(vec, log2(65000))
```

based on your condition where you test `2^vec>65000`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the solution I need. I didn't knew "any" ^^